# No Padlock in Firefox on interior pages - no mixed content

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, ssl

I'm at a loss.  Chrome shows my site with a green padlock throughout but I can't convince Firefox.

My homepage shows a padlock in Firefox (https://www.pianopronto.com)

However all the interior pages give me the "Grey" symbols and the "This website does not supply identity information."

I used "whynopadlock.com" and checked my pages (https://www.pianopronto.com/shop/) and they are clean with no mixed content (i.e. all images have https:// links)

Is this just Mozilla punishing me because I bought the "entry-level" SSL from GoDaddy?

Answer (score 0):

I can see the encryption activated everywhere. Try to open a shell and type

```
firefox -p -no-remote
```

create a new profile, start firefox with that profile and go to https://www.pianopronto.com/shop/

<s>Dude, it's normal. Firefox shows a gray lock instead of a green lock. See https://www.google.com/ for example :)</s>

Comment: True, but the question is not about the color, but about Firefox not showing a padlock at all, on some pages.

Comment: Probably it's caused by NoScript. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's the LinkedIn JavaScript that is messing up.

You can easily find it using Firebug. In its Net tab right-click the header to enable displaying "protocol" as well, and then sort by that.

[image]

Note that Chrome also warns you, but simply does not even *load* the non-HTTPS content:

[image]

Clicking that warning, and then enabling the unsafe content, will also make Chrome replace the green padlock with a red version.

Comment: (And on the About page, it's http://www.pianopronto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/JEN_AVATAR_BIGGER-150x150.jpg that is messing up.)